# Geany - How to execute code in terminal pane instead of external terminal

Tags: python, ide, geany

I really like Geany for writing Python code. When I click F5, it opens system's default terminal window and executes the code there.

There is also a terminal inside Geany window, the bottom pane and the last tab. What I want is the code to be executed there. Is it possible?

[image: Geany with terminal pane]

Answer (score 30, accepted):

After fiddling with the options, I found the way:

1. Right-click on terminal area and select "Preferences". It opens the general preferences window with Terminal tab opened.
2. There is an option: "Execute programs in the VTE". Checking this option does what I want.

Comment: This will work only on *x-systems as on Windows there is not VTE. You can also reach this via Edit->Preferences->Terminal

Answer (score -2):

if you are at the location of your file, just type python  in that terminal.